# Why is nomad listening on port 80?

Tags: nomad

Why is Nomad listening on port 80?

How can I change this to listen to another port?

I can't seem to find anything on Google relating to this.

**Edit: Opps I'm an idiot it wasn't Nomad that was listening on port 80... Can't delete this question either**

Answer (score 2):

According to this website https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.1e.com/news-insights/blogs/nomad-peer-peer-sharing/amp/ nomad uses http for p2p sharing. The default for this protocol is to use port 80 for communication, so that is probably why. I'm not sure how to go about changing it, but I would imagine it to be changeable.